# Checking registry value

Tags: vbscript, registry

Added the following lines to a verification script to check if Registry Value has been added and getting message

> Error occored while verifying the Registry Value for HKLM\SOFTWARE\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\MSR\REDIRON_MSR

Here is the code:

```
Dim strRegvalue

strRegvalue = g_objShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\MSR\REDIRON_MSR\")

If LCase(strRegvalue) = "True" Then
  Call WriteToLog("HKLM\SOFTWARE\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\MSR\REDIRON_MSR value verified successfully")
Else
  RegSuccessCode = 111
  Call WriteToLog("Error occurred while verifying the Registry Value for HKLM\SOFTWARE\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\MSR\REDIRON_MSR")
End If
```

Could you let me know where I'm going wrong with this.

Comment: Obviously `RegRead` did not return the value `"True"`. Does the default value of the `REDIRON_MSR` key contain the string `"True"`?

Comment: No, the default value does not contain the string "True"

Comment: Then your script is reporting the correct result. Or it's checking the wrong value. What is the script supposed to do? Check the existence of the `REDIRON_MSR` registry key?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Check the existence of the rediron_msr registry key.  The key does exist on machine I'm running this on.   Do you have another way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [`RegRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x05fawxd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to check for the existence of a registry key, you can do so by reading the key's default value. However, you must enable error handling then, because `RegRead` will raise an error if the value cannot be read (i.e. the key doesn't exist):

```
key = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\MSR\REDIRON_MSR\"

On Error Resume Next
g_objShell.RegRead key
If Err Then
  WScript.Echo key & " does not exist."
Else
  WScript.Echo key & " exists."
End If
On Error Goto 0
```

A better way would be to use the WMI registry methods, for instance [`EnumKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

Const HKLM = &h80000002
key = "SOFTWARE\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\MSR\REDIRON_MSR\"

retval = reg.EnumKey(HKLM, key, Null)
If retval = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo key & " exists."
Else
  WScript.Echo key & " does not exist."
End If
```

Comment: I tried both options and it's failing.  Not locating this reg key for some reason. Will try on another system.

Comment: @GA2015 How *exactly* is it "failing". Add `WScript.Echo Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description` and `WScript.Echo retval` to the "does not exist" branch of the first and second method respectively. What is the output? Did you verify that the registry path actually exists and you didn't make any typo with the path?

Comment: @GA2015 I just noticed that I mistakenly had the logic reversed in the second method. The key *exists* if the return value is 0. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry for delay got pulled onto something else.  Just tried the second revised option and it's looking good.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello I have another question not related to above can I ask you directly or do I have post it up.

Comment: @GA2015 Please post it as a new question. That's how this site works.